# How to use a QCombobox selection in a if loop?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qcombobox

I'm new to GUI's and I'm trying to make the user's choice in a combobox  change the outcome of my program.

Here's my Combobox:

```
self.popupItems1 = ("Option 1","Option 2")
self.popup1 = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
self.popup1.addItems(self.popupItems1)
self.popup1.setCurrentIndex(self.popupItems1.index("Option 1"))
self.popup1.move(10, 220)
```

I've done quite a lot of research but I can't seem to to figure this out, I'm guessing I should use something like this?

```
if self.popupItems1 == 'Option 1':
     do_something()
else:
     do_something_else()
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: If you need the program to do something right after the user select a choice in a combobox, you need to use signal and slots. If you want to process the choice later, like when the user click a button "ok", then the answer bellow will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the currently selected text in a QComboBox use the method `currentText()`, and if you want to get the index then use the method `currentIndex()`.

For example if your QComboBox is referenced by `self.popup1` then to get the selected text use :

```
text = self.popup1.currentText()
```

You can also get the index using the other method.

What you are looking for might be this :

```
if self.popup1.currentIndex() == 0 : # The first option
    do_something()
else : # Any other option
    do_something_else()
```

For more informations check [the documentation of QComboBox](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QComboBox.html).